# see full build console on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, build, console

Is there a way to see the full console output during the build process on eclipse? If I compile the project manually with ANT from the command line, there's a lot of interesting info. Eclipse seems to filter all the messages and only displays the serious errors.